# Model Regression Sklearn

Tags: python

Here is my program

```
 X = np.array([[1, 2, 4],[2, 3, 9]]).T    
 print(X)
 y = np.array([1, 4, 16])
 X_poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
 X_poly_return = X_poly.fit_transform(X)
 print(X_poly)
 model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False)
 model.fit(X_poly_return,y)
 print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
 print('Others: \n', model.intercept_)
 print(X_poly.powers_)
 X_predict = np.array([[3,3]])
 print ('prediction: \n') 
 print(model.predict(X_poly.transform(X_predict)))
```

Output:

```
 [-0.10133796 0.1456888 -0.01660059 0.54831516 0.45019822 -0.11496531] 
 powers : [[0 0] [1 0] [0 1] [2 0] [1 1] [0 2]] 
 prediction of [3,3] is [8.23785927]
```

So, the equation (the model is):

```
y = -0.11496531 * x *x + 0.45019822 * z *z     ?
```

My question how we have the prediction value 8.23785927 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the `powers`, shouldn't it be:

```
y = (-0.10133796)*(x^0)*(z^0) + (0.1456888)*(x^1)*(z^0) + 
    (-0.01660059)*(x^0)*(z^1) + (0.54831516)*(x^2)*(z^0) + 
    (0.45019822)*(x^1)*(z^1)  + (-0.11496531)*(x^0)*(z^2)
```

which for `x=z=3` becomes `8.2378593`.

Comment: thnks a lot (y)